# idle no importa librerias python

Tags: python

Hola mi problema es que cuando uso el idle para programar en python no me reconoce librerias que ya eh instalado como pygame. Ejemplo:

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Hola esto es lo que me salio al poner en la consola

```
"/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install pygame":

"/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip"
```

Sale lo mismo con sudo y sin el :(. Gracias por tu ayuda

```
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

Kali linux lo siento si lo olvide.

Al final esto funciono `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`, luego instale `pygame con sudo /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install pygame`
 gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Seguramente no has instalado en el interprete que usa el IDLE. En la consola interactiva del IDLE inserta esto `import sys; print(sys.executable)` lo que te muestre (ruta a ese intérprete) lo copias y pegas en una terminal/CMD y añade ` -m pip install pygame`. Si se instala correctamente debe importar sin problemas.

Comment: Hola esto es lo que me salio al poner en la consola "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install pygame":

"/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip"

Sale lo mismo con sudo y sin el :(. Gravias por tu ayuda

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra `which pip` en la terminal (del sistema, no del IDLE)? ¿Que sistema operativo usas exactamente?

Comment: muestra /usr/bin/pip

Comment: No mencionas el sistema operativo, posiblemente tengas python y pip enlazado al mismo. Si usas Ubuntu y python instalado desde los repositorios instala pip3 con `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` si no lo tienes y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: kali linux lo siento lo olvide :)

Comment: Ok, de todas formas Kali está también basada en debian... XD, es lo mismo `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`. Creo recordar que no viene pre-instalado como si lo hace Python3...

Comment: ¿Que sistema operativo usas exactamente?

Comment: Si has solucionado, en la parte inferior coloca lo que has realizado, dejando la pregunta para la pregunta y la zona de respuestas, para respuestas :D